# Flattening and unflattening a nested list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nested-lists, flatten

There are many recipes for flattening a nested list. I'll copy a solution here just for reference:

```
def flatten(x):
    result = []
    for el in x:
      if hasattr(el, "__iter__") and not isinstance(el, basestring):
        result.extend(flatten(el))
      else:
        result.append(el)
    return result
```

What I am interested in is the inverse operation, which reconstructs the list to its original format. For example:

```
L = [[array([[  24, -134],[ -67, -207]])], 
     [array([[ 204,  -45],[  99, -118]])], 
     [array([[  43, -154],[-122,  168]]), array([[  33, -110],[ 147,  -26],[ -49, -122]])]]

# flattened version

L_flat = [24, -134, -67, -207, 204, -45, 99, -118, 43, -154, -122, 168, 33, -110, 147, -26, -49, -122]
```

Is there an efficient way of flattening, saving indices and reconstructing to its original format?

Note that the list can be of arbitrary depth and may not have a regular shape, and will contain arrays of differing dimensions.

Of course, the flattening function should be also changed to store the structure of the list and the shape of the `numpy` arrays.

Comment: How are you supposed to know, from the flattened version, what it originally looked like? You have lost information in the flattening process.

Comment: Sure, the flattening function should be changed to store the structure of the list.

Comment: To an extent, you've answered your own question; you need to modify `flatten` to provide retain information on the structure of the list and the shapes of the arrays within it. For example, it could return `[[(2, 2)], [(2, 2)], [(2, 2), (3, 2)]]` alongside the flattened `L`. Then you will have to slice up `L_flat` accordingly and `reshape` the arrays from each slice.

Comment: Yeah right, I thought/hoped someone had a ready-to-use recipe for it.

Comment: Can you keep the original nested data structure while you are working on the flattened version?

Comment: No, the flattened version is cached on drive and loaded back at runtime. The reason I need the flattened version is to save it efficiently. Turned out it takes forever to cache a lot of "small arrays" with h5py.

Comment: Do you only need the flattened version for saving to disk? Could you just pickle the whole thing instead?

Comment: I could use something else. I am not bounded to h5py. But pickle is too slow.

Comment: Is pickle too slow because you measured it or because you suppose it will be? Are you aware of numpy.savez? Isn't the whole point of h5py to "…store huge amounts of numerical data, and easily manipulate that data from NumPy. For example, you can slice into multi-terabyte datasets stored on disk, as if they were real NumPy arrays. Thousands of datasets can be stored in a single file, categorized and tagged however you want." Why are you flattening at all?

Comment: pickle: measured over and over again and it has always been slow. np.savez: does not preserve the structure and it's slow. h5py: yes it's fast to save huge arrays, but apparently (consider also the time to loop) it's slow to load lot of small arrays.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that flattening, saving, reading and reconstituting in Pure Python is going to beat intrinsic (C) methods for doing the same. You should probably better define "slow relative to what". Relative to Pure C or FORTRAN? Certainly. Relative to XML? Probably not. Did you know that creating an `array(L)` will build your list into a numpy native array of arrays which will preserve structure? Have you tested the performance of p×q×N arrays with savez?

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for a solution to flatten and unflatten nested lists of numpy arrays, but only found this unanswered question, so I came up with this:

```
def _flatten(values):
    if isinstance(values, np.ndarray):
        yield values.flatten()
    else:
        for value in values:
            yield from _flatten(value)

def flatten(values):
    # flatten nested lists of np.ndarray to np.ndarray
    return np.concatenate(list(_flatten(values)))

def _unflatten(flat_values, prototype, offset):
    if isinstance(prototype, np.ndarray):
        shape = prototype.shape
        new_offset = offset + np.product(shape)
        value = flat_values[offset:new_offset].reshape(shape)
        return value, new_offset
    else:
        result = []
        for value in prototype:
            value, offset = _unflatten(flat_values, value, offset)
            result.append(value)
        return result, offset

def unflatten(flat_values, prototype):
    # unflatten np.ndarray to nested lists with structure of prototype
    result, offset = _unflatten(flat_values, prototype, 0)
    assert(offset == len(flat_values))
    return result
```

Example:

```
a = [
    np.random.rand(1),
    [
        np.random.rand(2, 1),
        np.random.rand(1, 2, 1),
    ],
    [[]],
]

b = flatten(a)

# 'c' will have values of 'b' and structure of 'a'
c = unflatten(b, a)
```

Output:

```
a:
[array([ 0.26453544]), [array([[ 0.88273824],
       [ 0.63458643]]), array([[[ 0.84252894],
        [ 0.91414218]]])], [[]]]
b:
[ 0.26453544  0.88273824  0.63458643  0.84252894  0.91414218]
c:
[array([ 0.26453544]), [array([[ 0.88273824],
       [ 0.63458643]]), array([[[ 0.84252894],
        [ 0.91414218]]])], [[]]]
```

License: WTFPL

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I come up with, which turned out to be ~30x faster than iterating over the nested list and loading individually.

```
def flatten(nl):
    l1 = [len(s) for s in itertools.chain.from_iterable(nl)]
    l2 = [len(s) for s in nl]

    nl = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        itertools.chain.from_iterable(nl)))

    return nl,l1,l2

def reconstruct(nl,l1,l2):
    return np.split(np.split(nl,np.cumsum(l1)),np.cumsum(l2))[:-1]

L_flat,l1,l2 = flatten(L)
L_reconstructed = reconstruct(L_flat,l1,l2)
```

A better solution solution would work iteratively for an arbitrary number of nested levels.

Comment: This gave me an error
`object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()`

Answer (score -1):

You're building a paradox: you want to flatten the object, but you don't want to flatten the object, retaining its structural information somewhere in the object.

So the pythonic way to do this is *not* to flatten the object, but writing a class that will have an `__iter__` that allows you to sequentially (ie. in a flat manner) go through the elements of the underlying object. That will be about as fast as the conversion to a flat thing (if only applied once per element), and you don't duplicate or change the original non-flat container.

Comment: My use case is that I need to apply a function on the sorted elements of the array.

Comment: Another common use case is working with vectorized functions. You reshape down to one dimension, apply the function, then reshape the result back to the original format. Numpy's reshape function assumes full matrices, not (potentially ragged) nested lists.